# Method exists and is not recognized..."Sub or function not defined vba"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module called "UsefulStuff" which have a function:

```
Public Sub SuspendUpdating(message As String)
    Application.StatusBar = message
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
End Sub
```

When I call this is another module "modJira":

```
Public Sub ImportFromJira()

    Dim resultXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument, resultNode As IXMLDOMElement


    Dim nodeContainer As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim rowCount As Integer, colCount As Integer
    Dim fixVersionString As String
    Dim dumpRange As Range, tempValue As Variant

    'Dim usefulStuff As New usefulStuff

    Call SuspendUpdating("Getting data from Jira...")
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try right clicking on the SuspendUpdating in the Jira mod, and clicking definition, see where it takes you.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Well, guess where it would take him based on the error message about the sub not being defined...

Comment: @THorsten, That's what we're trying to find out, see if its there to call or not.

Comment: Are both procedures in the same workbook?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav If the "compiler" says it can't find it, there's no point in doing what you're suggesting.

Comment: @thorsten.  Trying to advise of debug steps and essentially mark's question, it could be corrupt or anything.  Which one of my team had this week or last, we had to roll back.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav What I'm trying to say is: Mark's question is valid as he wants the **user** to do something. Your suggestion doesn't lead anywhere in my opinion, as you are trying to use the same mechanism that says it can not find something to look the same thing up. If the compiler already says the function can not be found, how should the IDE be able to crosslink to it? If Visual Studio told you in your C# code that method X in class Y can not be found there's no point trying to go to definition, as the IDE won't be able to *find* the definition, otherwise the compiler would not have errored.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Of course you can suggest doing that, all I'm saying is that it's probably a waste of time.

Comment: I really dont care to argue about this to be honest with you, i was trying to go through how i would start debugging, my 1st try would be to see if it's defined (as the post question illudes to) i'd also then try and find it in the code, it could be within a class, as i've done in the past clsSTRINGMANIPULATION for example, for my string functions...  Without being real time posts can seem redundnant and useless.  Hence the reason i didnt put it as an answer.

Comment: When I click on "definition" I get "Identifier under cursor is not recognized"

http://postimg.org/image/jbu4idmib/
http://postimg.org/image/imj6bp9bf/

Answer (score 0):

The commented-out line

```
'Dim usefulStuff As New usefulStuff
```

implies that `usefulStuff` is a *class* module. If this is the case then you will get the error message that you mention.

The fix is to uncomment-out that line and then invoke the sub as a method call:

```
Dim usefulStuff As New usefulStuff

usefullStuff.SuspendUpdating "Getting data from Jira..."
```

If this doesn't fix it my guess is that it is in some other workbook. Assuming that the workbook is open and is named `Mystery.xlsm` then the following line should work

```
Application.Run "Mystery.xlsm!SuspendUpdating", "Getting data from Jira..."
```

Comment: Is it in a different workbook? If it is in a standard module and you are trying to call it from a standard module in the same workbook, your project has become corrupt. Try 1) exporting `usefulStuff`, 2) deleting it from the project, 3) importing it again. Somewhat oddly, this sometimes work. See this: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: With "application.run (...) seems to work.." when I run the macro "ImportFromJira" I got a error from this point.

Comment: I delete the file and import it again and i got error on the line "Application.Run "Mystery.xlsm!SuspendUpdating", "Getting data from Jira...""

Comment: If you just exported it from a different workbook and then imported it into your current workbook then it should now be in the same workbook as the calling code. In this case just call it directly (no need to use Application.Run or quality the name by the workbook).